# How can I call a controller/view action from a mailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

In my rails application I've created a business daily report. There is some non-trivial logic for showing it (all kind of customizable parameters that are used for filtering in the model, a controller that calls that model and some non-trivial view for it, for example, some of the columns are row-spanning over several rows).

Now I wish to send this report nightly (with fixed parameters), in addition to the user ability to generate a customize report in my web site. Of course, I wish not to re-write/duplicate my work, including the view.

My question is how can I call the controller action from my mailer so that it will be as if the page was requested by a user (without sending a get request as a browser, which I wish to avoid, of course)?

Answer (score 3):

In answer to your question is if you are generating some sort of pdf report then go with using the [wicke_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) gem does exactly that generates pdfs. To send a report on a nightly basis the best thing for this is to implement some sort of cron job that runs at a particular time which you can do using the [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem. You can do something like:

**schedule.rb**

```
every :day, :at => '12:00am'
  runner User.send_report
end
```

With this at hand you can see that you call the `send_report` method sits inside the User model class as shown below:

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 

   def self.send_report
    ReportMailer.report_pdf(@user).deliver
  end
end
```

Inside send_report we call the mailer being ReportMailer which is the name of the class for our mailer and the method being report_pdf and pass in the user. **BUT** remember this is an example I have here I am not sure the exact specified information you want in a report.

**Mailer**

```
  class ReportMailer< ActionMailer::Base

   default :from => DEFAULT_FROM
     def report_pdf(user)
       @user = user
       mail(:subject => "Overtime", :to => user.email) do |format|
         format.text # renders report.text.erb for body of email
         format.pdf do
           attachments["report.pdf"] = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
            render_to_string(:pdf => "report",:template => 'report/index.pdf.erb', 
              :layouts => "pdf.html"))
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

Inside the mailer there are a variety of things going on but the most important part is inside the `format.pdf` block that uses a variety of `wicked_pdf` methods (this is assuming that you are using wicked_pdf btw. Inside the block you create a new WickedPDF pdf object and render it to a string. Then provide it with the name of the report, the template and the layout. It is important that you create a template. This usually will where the report will be displaying from. The file type is a `.pdf.erb` this means that when this view or report is generated in the view the embedded ruby tags are being parsed in and the output is going to be a pdf format.

**UserController**

```
def report
    @user = User.scoped
    if params[:format] == 'pdf'
     #Do some stuff here
      User.send_report(@users)
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render :pdf => "#{Date.today.strftime('%B')} Report",
               :header => {:html => {:template => 'layouts/pdf.html.erb'}}
      end
    end
  end
```

The key thing you asked that I picked up on.

> how can I call the controller action from my mailer

In the controller simply collate a scope of Users, then check the format is a pdf, providing it is do some stuff. Then it will run the method `send_report` which I earlier highlighted in the user model class (Btw in your words this is the controller calling the model). Then inside the respond block for this there is a `format.pdf` so that you can generate the pdf. Once again note that you need a template for the core design of the pdf, which is similar to how rails generates an application.html.erb in the layouts. However here we have a pdf.html.erb defined. So that this can be called anywhere again in your application should you want to generate another pdf in your application somewhere else.

Think I've provided a substantial amount of information to set you off in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Anyway note that I don't need a PDF, I want to sent the HTML page as is (anyway it will not be a PDF), so I didn't try the entire overhead of using the PDF. My problem is that the call to render_to_string fails to go through the controller that generates the original web-page, and fails to collect the data as in the web page. Of course I can try a new controller with duplicate code, but I wish to avoid that. I want to call the exact same logic as is used for displaying the web page.

Comment: I think I should treat the mailer as parallel to the controller, duplicate the minor logic of the controller (just a call to some class) and use "render_as_string" to trigger the view.

Comment: Well in that case you could do something like that in your controller and call `render_to_string` but what format is this report going to be in?